# Invite users to collaborate on project

Tags: meteor

I am developing a project management app with Meteor. A user can create a new account and then create projects. In a project he must be able to invite collaborators. The process for this should be something like this:

- The userId of the collaborator will be added to the project userId's
- The collaborator sees the project on his page with projects and he can confirm collaboration by clicking a link or button
- The collaborator can collaborate to the project
- The owner sees the collaborator in the list of collaborators

The project should have a list of collaborator userId's:

```
Project = {
  _id: 'fpoierj9',
  name: 'Sample',
  userIds: [
    'opijo42',
    'ik03agg',
    'po32a0v',
  ],
};
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Well, what should the differences be? Without knowing that, the easiest solutions would be to use the query string.

Comment: After your last edit, your question is bound to be closed as "too broad", by the way.

Comment: You are right, this is too broad. Back to the drawing board :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is along the same lines as the problem I discussed in a blog post I wrote while I was at Differential, earlier this year.

http://differential.com/blog/tokenized-access-and-invited-use-in-meteor

Replace the 'chat' example I used with your 'project' and you're on your way.

...ok, a summary by request. A url containing a token is created for each invitation sent to a user. The token is also stored in the system with access to the collaborative instance (chat, project, whatever). When the invited user follows the invitation url, the app routes them into the instance.

Comment: Essentially, this is a link-only answer. If you added a summary of the linked-to article this could be a great answer.

Comment: For a question as broad as this one, I think it fine to just pass on a link and essentially say "do some reading"

Comment: This link is now dead, which is exactly why it is critical to provide the *actual answer* in the body of the answer.